# What is the Xpath in a nested table with two different class names

Tags: xpath

This is the html:

[image]

I need to extract the two elements which have "Oslo-Gardermoen"
What would the Xpath to that?

**HTML:**

```
<table class="avadaytable" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <colgroup class="avadaycolgroup">
      <col class="col1">
      <col class="col2">
      <col class="col3">
      <col class="col4">
      <col class="col5">
      <col class="col6">
      <col class="col7">
      <col class="col8">
      <col class="col9">
   </colgroup>
   <thead>
      <tr class="rowspacer">
         <td class="startcell">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="endcell">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3" class="firstrowheadercell">
            <div class="statictooltipclick ToolTipSHCompare pricetable" onclick="
               dataLayer.push(
               {'event': 'trackEvent','eventCategory': 'Select Flight','eventAction': 'Compare fare types','eventLabel': ''}
               )
               ">Compare fare types</div>
         </th>
         <th class="standardfareheadercell tooltipclick endcell" colspan="6"><span class="currencyinfo">All fares per person in GBP</span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th class="departureheadercell" rowspan="1">
            <div class="content">Departure</div>
         </th>
         <th class="arrivalheadercell" rowspan="1">
            <div class="content">Arrival</div>
         </th>
         <th class="detailsheadercell" rowspan="1">
            <div class="content">Details</div>
         </th>
         <td onclick="
            dataLayer.push(
            {'event': 'trackEvent','eventCategory': 'Select Flight','eventAction': 'Compare fare types','eventLabel': ''}
            )
            " class="statictooltipclick ToolTipSHCompare select1headercell standardlowfareheadercell " colspan="2">
            <div class="infoicon">LowFare </div>
         </td>
         <td onclick="
            dataLayer.push(
            {'event': 'trackEvent','eventCategory': 'Select Flight','eventAction': 'Compare fare types','eventLabel': ''}
            )
            " class="statictooltipclick ToolTipSHCompare select1headercell standardlowfareheadercell " colspan="2">
            <div class="infoicon">LowFare+ </div>
         </td>
         <td onclick="
            dataLayer.push(
            {'event': 'trackEvent','eventCategory': 'Select Flight','eventAction': 'Compare fare types','eventLabel': ''}
            )
            " class="statictooltipclick ToolTipSHCompare select2headercell standardflexheadercell endcell" colspan="2">
            <div class="infoicon">Flex </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="oddrow rowinfo1 ">
         <td class="depdest" title="Flight DY1072">
            <div class="content emphasize">13:10</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content emphasize">15:40</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">Direct</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare0" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|1|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare0" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">37.70</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare0" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus0" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|9|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus0" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">55.70</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus0" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardflex">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex0" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|2|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex0" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|2|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardflex endcell">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">221.50</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex0" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|2|0">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddrow rowinfo2">
         <td class="depdest" title="Flight DY1072">
            <div class="content">Oslo-Gardermoen</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content">Riga</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">Duration: 1h 30m</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfare" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare0" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|1|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfareplus" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus0" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|9|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardflex endcell" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex0" value="0|DY1072OSLRIX|2|0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddrow lastrow">
         <td colspan="3" class="routeinfotextcell routeinfoimagecell">
            <div class="content">
               <ul class="flightinfolist">
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxWifi" title="Click for more info">WiFi included (*)</li>
                  <li class="plaintext">Operated by Norwegian Air Shuttle</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="evenrow rowinfo1 ">
         <td class="depdest" title="Flight DY1074">
            <div class="content emphasize">20:40</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content emphasize">23:10</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">Direct</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare1" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|1|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare1" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">33.00</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare1" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus1" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|9|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus1" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">51.00</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus1" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardflex">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex1" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|2|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex1" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|2|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardflex endcell">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">221.50</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex1" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|2|0">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="evenrow rowinfo2">
         <td class="depdest" title="Flight DY1074">
            <div class="content">Oslo-Gardermoen</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content">Riga</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">Duration: 1h 30m</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfare" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare1" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|1|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfareplus" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus1" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|9|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardflex endcell" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex1" value="0|DY1074OSLRIX|2|0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="evenrow lastrow">
         <td colspan="3" class="routeinfotextcell routeinfoimagecell">
            <div class="content">
               <ul class="flightinfolist">
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxWifi" title="Click for more info">WiFi included (*)</li>
                  <li class="plaintext">Operated by Norwegian Air International</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddrow rowinfo1 ">
         <td class="depdest" title="">
            <div class="content emphasize">17:25</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content emphasize">21:50</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">1 stop</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare2" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare2" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">124.80</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare2" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus2" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus2" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">142.80</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus2" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardflex">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex2" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex2" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardflex endcell">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">360.50</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex2" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddrow rowinfo2">
         <td class="depdest" title="">
            <div class="content">Oslo-Gardermoen</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content">Riga</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">Duration: 3h 25m</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfare" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare2" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfareplus" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus2" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardflex endcell" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex2" value="0|DY948OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddrow lastrow">
         <td colspan="3" class="routeinfotextcell routeinfoimagecell">
            <div class="content">
               <ul class="flightinfolist">
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxWifi" title="Click for more info">WiFi included (*)</li>
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxTransit" title="Click for more info">1 stop (55m) in Copenhagen</li>
                  <li class="plaintext">Operated by Norwegian Air Shuttle, Norwegian Air International</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="evenrow rowinfo1 ">
         <td class="depdest" title="">
            <div class="content emphasize">15:20</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content emphasize">21:50</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">1 stop</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare3" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare3" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">124.80</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare3" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus3" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus3" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">142.80</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus3" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardflex">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex3" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex3" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardflex endcell">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">360.50</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex3" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="evenrow rowinfo2">
         <td class="depdest" title="">
            <div class="content">Oslo-Gardermoen</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content">Riga</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">Duration: 5h 30m</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfare" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare3" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfareplus" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus3" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardflex endcell" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex3" value="0|D83224OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="evenrow lastrow">
         <td colspan="3" class="routeinfotextcell routeinfoimagecell">
            <div class="content">
               <ul class="flightinfolist">
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxWifi" title="Click for more info">WiFi included (*)</li>
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxTransit" title="Click for more info">1 stop (3h 0m) in Copenhagen</li>
                  <li class="plaintext">Operated by Norwegian Air International</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddrow rowinfo1 ">
         <td class="depdest" title="">
            <div class="content emphasize">14:30</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content emphasize">21:50</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">1 stop</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare4" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare4" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">124.80</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare4" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus4" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus4" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">142.80</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus4" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardflex">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex4" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex4" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardflex endcell">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">360.50</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex4" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddrow rowinfo2">
         <td class="depdest" title="">
            <div class="content">Oslo-Gardermoen</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content">Riga</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">Duration: 6h 20m</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfare" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare4" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfareplus" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus4" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardflex endcell" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex4" value="0|DY940OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddrow lastrow">
         <td colspan="3" class="routeinfotextcell routeinfoimagecell">
            <div class="content">
               <ul class="flightinfolist">
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxWifi" title="Click for more info">WiFi included (*)</li>
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxTransit" title="Click for more info">1 stop (3h 50m) in Copenhagen</li>
                  <li class="plaintext">Operated by Norwegian Air International</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="evenrow rowinfo1 ">
         <td class="depdest" title="">
            <div class="content emphasize">22:10</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content emphasize">09:20 <span class="offsetdays" title="Next day">+1</span></div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">1 stop</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare5" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare5" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfare">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">124.80</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare5" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus5" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus5" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardlowfareplus">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">142.80</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus5" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0">
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect standardflex">
            <div class="content" title=""><input type="radio" id="FlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex5" name="FlightSelectOutbound" class="radio-ajax" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex5" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0">
         </td>
         <td class="fareselect standardflex endcell">
            <div class="content" title=""><label class="label seatsokfare" title="GBP">360.50</label></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex5" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="evenrow rowinfo2">
         <td class="depdest" title="">
            <div class="content">Oslo-Gardermoen</div>
         </td>
         <td class="arrdest">
            <div class="content">Riga</div>
         </td>
         <td class="duration">
            <div class="content">Duration: 10h 10m</div>
         </td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfare" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFare5" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|1|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardlowfareplus" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardLowFarePlus5" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|9|0"></td>
         <td class="inputselect avafareinfo standardflex endcell" rowspan="2" colspan="2">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="hdnFlightSelectOutboundStandardFlex5" value="0|D83246OSLCPHD83320CPHRIX|2|0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="evenrow lastrow">
         <td colspan="3" class="routeinfotextcell routeinfoimagecell">
            <div class="content">
               <ul class="flightinfolist">
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxWifi" title="Click for more info">WiFi included (*)</li>
                  <li class="tooltipclick TooltipBoxNightstop" title="Click for more info">This route has an overnight stop. Departure Copenhagen 07:00</li>
                  <li class="plaintext">Operated by Norwegian Air International</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: https://www.norwegian.com/uk/ipc/availability/avaday?AdultCount=1&A_City=RIX&D_City=OSL&D_Month=201910&D_Day=13&IncludeTransit=false&TripType=1&CurrencyCode=GBP&dFare=33&mode=ab

Comment: No, post the actual HTML in the body of your question, which should stand on its own if the link dies in the future.  Also, never post images of code or markup -- it prevents copy-and-paste for verifying answers.  See also [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath.

```
//td[@class='depdest']/div[@class='content']
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Can you please tell me how did you get that path?

Comment: can you please tell me the interface you've used to get the Xpath like this?

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output  FYI, this will support both xpath1 and xpath2.